# How do you mock the 'panache' persist method for a Quarkus test

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

Was writing some Quarkus test and I had issues trying to mock the .persist() method.

Comment: Add which are issues you found and show your efforts to solve the problems. This question is too generic and official quarkus doc about Panache contains all necessary information to work with Panache and Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

If a method contains optional parameters such as it does in the persist method, you have to capture those even if your code is not using them. I was able to do that by just using they `any()` matcher as shown below.

```java
Mockito.when(query.firstResult()).thenReturn(null);
        PanacheMock.mock(MyDAO.class);
        Mockito.when(MyDAO.find(Mockito.any(String.class), Mockito.any(Object.class))).thenReturn(query);
```

Note you can just replace the `Mockito.any(String.class)` with whatever matcher you want.